# Range DataAnnotation doesn't work (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, range, data-annotations

I'm trying to add the Range DataAnnotation to a property in my EF model:

```
public class Book {
...
[Range(100.0, 400.0)]
public double Price {get;set;}
...
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I drop the database and recreate it, but I see no range constraint in the database on the price column of the Book table.

I can also add a book from the code as follows:

```
Book b = new Book() {
...
    Price = 50.0
...
}
_context.Book.Add(b);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

...and it adds the book without errors even though the Price is below the range specified.

Why isn't Range working? The database is SQL Server. Can I not implement range constraints in SQL Server? Is this meant for some other database like Oracle?

Comment: As far as I know the `RangeAttribute` is not designed to have any effect on the database schema, regardless of provider (SQL Server or otherwise). However, it still can't hurt to have it in the code where you're validating the model.